# PyQt5: Вывод текста построчно из виджета QTextEdit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, split, qtextedit

При вызове метода `toPlainText()` переменная `groups` получает **3 строки** как единую строку.

Мне нужно, чтобы из элемента `textEdit`, в список `group_list` заносились значения именно **построчно**. 
Как это реализовать?

Имеется код:

```
groups = self.ui.textEdit.toPlainText()
groups_list = []
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод Python string.split()

Syntax: `string.split(separator, maxsplit)`

**separator:** Необязательный. Определяет разделитель для использования при разбиении строки. По умолчанию любой пробел является разделителем

**maxsplit:** Необязательный. Определяет, сколько делится. Значением по умолчанию является -1, что означает 'все вхождения'

Разбейте текст на список, где каждая строка является элементом списка:

```
groups_list = self.ui.textEdit.toPlainText().split('\n')
```